# How should I apply a sub-dermal skin map in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, texture-painting

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.yurialexander.com/tutorials/realistic-skin-detail-and-color/) in zbrush and I am going to bring the model and textures into blender but I was wondering how can I apply a subdermal map like they made in cycles and what is the purpose of it? Thanks!